# C++ global variable initialization by shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

**shared.h**

```
    #pragma once
    
    extern int uninitialized_variable;
    extern int initialized_variable;
    
    void print();
```

**shared.cpp**

```
    // shared.cpp
    #include "shared.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int uninitialized_variable;
    int initialized_variable = 8;
    
    void print() {
        printf("%d\n", uninitialized_variable);
        printf("%d\n", initialized_variable);
    }
```

**main.cpp**

```
    #include "shared.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    
    int main() {
        printf("%d\n", uninitialized_variable);
        printf("%d\n", initialized_variable);
        print();
    }
```

```
g++ -O0 -pedantic -std=c++11 -fPIC shared.cpp -c -o shared.o
g++ -shared -o libshared.so shared.o

g++ -O0 -pedantic -std=c++11 main.cpp -L. -lshared
```

When I run ./a.out, the result is 0 8 0 8.
But I can't find the reason why `initialized_variable` is 8.

Since I used gbd the check where exactly is `initialized_variable`，and found that it is in the .bss in a.out。But in the .init section of the libshared.so, i can't find any code to do the initialization of the `initialized_variable` in a.out's .bss.

Who and when the `initialized_variable` is initalized?

Comment: I think the initiaizied_variable is initialized in shared.cpp, then you include it in main,cpp. When you include and extern the global variable, then main.cpp already know the existence of initiaizied_variable. If not, you program will have error.

Answer (score 0):

It's provided as raw data in the `.data` segment:

```
Disassembly of section .data:

....

0000000000004028 <initialized_variable>:
    4028:   08 00                   or     %al,(%rax)
    402a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
```

Ignore the assembly as this is not executable data.  Note that the offset where `initialized_variable` lives contains the four bytes (in hex here): 08 00 00 00.  Interpreted as a 4-byte signed little-endian integer, this is the value 8.

Quite simply, the value is 8 as soon as the library is mapped into memory.  No additional instructions are required to initialize it.

Comment: However, the .data section is belong to library. And the initialized_variable in got is point to .bss in the binary.